# My javascript function works just within the html file, but if a move it to is own file doesnt work why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my project, I am also using bootstrap 3, HTML, CSS.
I have correctly linked the HTML document to the javaScript file.
this is the code:

```js
 var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Please add html code as well.

Comment: Where and how have you included your js in the html file ?

Comment: Please define "_doesn't work_". Do you see any error messages in the DevConsole?

Comment: As you have not mentioned how you are calling your JS file, just early thoughts - please call your JS file at the end of your HTML page.

Comment: have you tried to load the js file with `defer` attribute? Like `<script src='pathToFile' defer></script>`